# Latex editor suggestion

Tags: support, mathjax, editor

It takes me lot of time to type problems and answers directly. It would be of great help if anyone can suggest me any good latex editor so as to type answer and problems faster.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You might have a look at some Q&A on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editors?sort=votes). We also have some related questions here at meta: [WYSIWYG for math formulas?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127/wysiwyg-for-math-formulas),
[Editors for composing posts before posting on to math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024/editors-for-composing-posts-befor-posting-on-to-math-se) and
[MathJax: better way to prepare a Math.StackExchange question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4735/).

Comment: [See these comparisons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors).Well Bakoma tex is very good and there is a real time preview in it just like this site but its not free :(.
Texmaker and auctex are also good.I have used those.

Comment: Also, which platform do you use?  I type questions in Kile (linux platform) and just copy it over.

Comment: Another related question: [Are there any plug-ins or software programs (preferably free) that you use to generate MathJax equations and edit them?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/20896)

Comment: A related question on the main site: [Free software to create equations and export to various formats](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/146383).

Answer (score 3):

Check out this one:

http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php?lang=en-en

Answer (score 3):

There are some decent equation editors out there, for example:

- [Number Empire](http://www.numberempire.com/texequationeditor/equationeditor.php)
- [Sci Weavers](http://www.sciweavers.org/free-online-latex-equation-editor)
- [Hamline](http://sites.hamline.edu/~arundquist/equationeditor/)

**RECOMMENDATION:** I recommend you to learn MathJax; it's not too hard! Everybody learns through practice. There are [some resources](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/texer.php) that encourage you to learn by practicing.

Comment: I think that equations editors like these actually help to learn how to type MathJax. I'm learning MathJax, and when I don't know a latex macro, I just search in the CodeCogs equation editor. Very fast and convenient way to learn Mathjax/Latex.

Comment: @Kasper: That is right too :) although, I did more than looking at equation editors. I've never used an equation editor personally; I asked questions about MathJax or used to hang around on sites seeing how _they_ wrote it.

Comment: I learned most by googling, until I found out this one. Most macros I know by head now, but I prefer an editor for things like matrices, and aligned equations. I think that using an editor is just faster (at least for me).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answer and also recommend MathJax. I've built SaturnAPI to support MathJax (along with Octave and a bunch of others). Here is an example: https://saturnapi.com/fullstack/equations-and-matrices