# Can I use Mathematics Stack Exchange's MathJax for uses different than those intended?

Tags: support, mathjax

I am participating in the IYMC and need to type some answers. As a member of this site for $9$ months, I find myself much more comfortable typing in MathJax than in Microsoft Word. So I hope that I can simply type in what I need in the body and use the screenshots to create a pdf file with my answers. I will not be posting the question, only use the display screen below it. So I was wondering if it was a copyright infringement and if I should mention where I typed the answers. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: No, I think you'd be fine. Or you could use [CodeCogs LaTeX editor](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php?lang=en-en) if you prefer.

Comment: Oh thanks. But MSE just feels more natural.

Comment: Microsoft Word supports a reasonable number of LaTeX commands.

Comment: Hmm I didn't know that. I was having to subscript, superscript, copying and pasting $\pi$ and wasting a lot of time in general. But I am already on the last question here so no point switching now.

Comment: To be fair, the amount of effort that it would take to set up screenshots of a bunch of MSE MathJax would probably be less than the effort to learn how to use LaTeX on a site like ShareLatex (and there you can actually edit as needed, unlike in a screenshot).

Comment: Where these sites hidden on the deep net or worse, page $2$ of search results whenever I was searching? Thank you for your help. I hope that I at least reach the finals$\ldots$

Comment: Why not just $\TeX$ up your work?  If you don't want to install a $\TeX$ system on your system, you can use an online system such as [Overleaf](http://overleaf.com).

Comment: Can I download my work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the preview for whatever purpose. The preview is generated by your web browser, which runs some JavaScript downloaded from the site. If you are not submitting text, you are just running a program on your computer.

That said, there are better solutions that allow you to also save the files and edit them again later (something you cannot do with a screenshot). [StackEdit 4](https://stackedit.io/editor) is one such: as the name suggests, it is a web based editor very similar to what we use here. (StackEdit 5 diverged from it by switching from MathJaX to KaTeX.)

Comment: Thanks you for those, I will keep them in mind as I will need them for further stages. However, I am done for now but thank you.

Comment: The suggestion of StackEdit4 is apt.  For additional suggestions see the previous [Latex editor suggestion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5053/latex-editor-suggestion) and the posts that are linked to it.